# How can I convert a histogram (2D) into 2 pdf in zfit?

Tags: zfit

I am trying to do some 2d spectra fitting with the help of zfit.
The pdf I want to use comes from ROOT TH2D.
Is there any method to convert the input Th2D into a 2D pdf directly in zfit?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: FYI: with the newest zfit update, this is now possible to do, see my (edited) answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Update

zfit supports now binned PDFs ([see here](https://zfit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_api/pdf/_generated/binned_pdf/zfit.pdf.HistogramPDF.html)) in the newest version (to be installed with `pip install -U zfit --pre`) and allows to load histograms. They should be a Histogram from [hist](https://github.com/scikit-hep/hist) if possible, using uproot you should be able to convert one to another.

An introductory tutorial to binned fits can be found [here](https://zfit-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/components/30%20-%20Binned%20models.html)

### Old answer

There is currently no direct way but [there is Work In Progress](https://github.com/zfit/zfit/pull/272) to implement binned fitting.

In general, I would advise to use [hist](https://hist.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) within Python, as it can be used directly with zfit in the future.

A way to implement this now is to use the hists `density`, create a custom PDF ([such as here](https://github.com/zfit/zfit-tutorials/blob/master/components/62%20-%20Multidim%20Custom%20PDF.ipynb)) in zfit and set `zfit.run.set_graph_mode(False)` and `zfit.run.set_autograd_mode(False)`.